# NSNumber unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, exception, nsstring, nsnumber

The following code

```
  NSMutableString *a = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  NSMutableString *pivot     =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    int i= 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < [columns count]; i++)
    {


        if ([[[data objectForKey:pivot] class] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        {
             sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, i+1,[[columns objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]);

        }
        else
        {
            // NSLog(@"kind of class %@ %@",NSStringFromClass([[data objectForKey:pivot] class]) ,[data objectForKey:pivot]);
            [pivot setString:[columns objectAtIndex:i]];
            [a setString:(NSString*)[data objectForKey:pivot]];
            sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, i+1, [a UTF8String], -1, 0);

        }
    }
    a     = nil;
    pivot = nil;
```

raises an exception

```
 kind of class __NSCFConstantString
  -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc94c240
```

But the log clearly says that `[data objectForKey:pivot]` is a String! And the `test` variable is always 0!

I checked in the debug and actually  `[data objectForKey:pivot]` is a Number. And in fact I use an `if` (not shown) to check if it is a number or not. Obviously, the `if` fails...

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the `class` to a string when you try to format it this way, try to get the string name from the class with [`NSStringFromClass(class)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromClass) :

```
 id pivotObject = [data objectForKey:pivot];
 NSLog(@"kind of class %@", NSStringFromClass([pivotObject class]));
 if ([pivotObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
     [pivot setString:[columns objectAtIndex:i]];
     [a setString:pivotObject];
 }
```

Also the `isKindOfClass:` returns a `BOOL` not `int`.

### **But most importantly**:

I think the error in the `[pivot setString:[columns objectAtIndex:i]]` line, since here you change the pivot variable and then retrieve it from data, But since the pivot variable is changed you request a different key from the data dictionary. This you will get an other value. My code I only grab the pivotData once from data.

Comment: What is the object you get from `[columns objectAtIndex:i]`

Comment: Uhmm..ok. I put another variable in the code to check the class. See the edited code

Comment: @giuseppe You aren't using the same kind of NSLog. Use NSStringFromClass and you'll see the real class of the object.

Comment: Same. Nothing changes (@Abizem).

Comment: @rckoenes. I used your code, but now integer values become empty in the setString!

Comment: @giuseppe To problem is that you change the value of the `pivot` variable in `[pivot setString:[columns objectAtIndex:i]]` since you did not post you hole code I can't help you any further. I think that you code is broken because of you change the variable mid way. Move this to the end or take all value in the start in temp variable and **DONT** change them.